# проверьте мои ошибки

Tags: грамматика

кому? Директору фонда по управлению госудатственным имуществам    А.Сергееву 
 кем? начальником юридическим отделом аппарата Верховно совета

как можно задавать вопросы и талковать предложений?
в чем отличие этих  котором,который.которая которые?
У меня не получаеться составить сложные предложения.
какие советы?
именно какую тему изучит?

Comment: Если русский для вас не родной и вы знаете английский можете спросить здесь: http://russian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Здесь очень много ошибок. Я мог бы написать правильные варианты (чуть позже сделаю), но разбирать и объяснять каждую - это здесь не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас проблемы с союзными словами "который, которая, которые", значит, у Вас проблема со сложноподчинённым предложением. Вот материал по теме. Думаю, здесь достаточно понятно.
http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/452

Сложноподчинённое предложение состоит из главного и зависимого, которое называется придаточным. Зависимое предложение заменяет какой-то член предложения, и вид его мы определяем по вопросу.

Я живу в доме (**каком?**), **который** стоит на окраине.На вопрос какой? отвечает определение, значит, это придаточное предложение определительное, т.к. оно замещает определение, а присоединяется к главному с помощью союзного слова **который**. Оно стоит в том же роде и  числе, что и слово, от которого мы ставим вопрос. Дом-ед.ч., муж.род, который-ед.ч., муж.род.

Я знаю(**о чём? что?), что** пора идти домой. 
На вопрос  о чём? отвечает дополнение, это предложение изъяснительное(оно дополняет речь, изъяснение).

Я сегодня был там(**где?), где** жил Пушкин.- замещает обстоятельство места, значит, это придаточное обстоятельственное места.

Answer (score 0):

**Кому?** Директору фонда по управлению госудатственным имуществам А.Сергееву.
**Кем?** Начальником юридическ**ого** отдел**а** аппарата Верховно**го** **С**овета...

> Как можно задавать вопросы и т**o**лковать предложени**я**?

Уточните вопрос. Предложения не надо "толковать". Их надо правильно понимать.

> В чем отличие этих котором,который.которая которые?

В падеже и грамматическом роде

> У меня не получае**тся** составить сложные предложения. Какие **будут** советы? Какую тему изучить?

Судя по характеру ваших ошибок,вам надо поднимать общий уровень русского. Не стоит ограничиваться какой-то одной темой. Возможно, здесь есть специалисты РКИ (Русский для иностранцев), тогда они дадут более подробные рекомендации.